# legendUrl defined in GetCapabilities document has OnlineResource that provides an href url to the legend graphic

Tags: geoserver

legendUrl defined in GetCapabilities document has OnlineResource that provides an href url to the legend graphic. However this link always defines the height and width of the legend to be 20 x 20 even in the legend is much larger - for instance a custom legend graphic for a raster layer.

For example:

```
<Layer queryable="1" opaque="0">
<Name>layer_name</Name>
<Title>layer_title</Title>
<Abstract/>
<KeywordList>
<Keyword>geotools_coverage</Keyword>
<Keyword>WCS</Keyword>
<Keyword>MBTiles</Keyword>
</KeywordList>
<CRS>EPSG:3857</CRS>
<CRS>CRS:84</CRS>
<EX_GeographicBoundingBox>
<westBoundLongitude>-97.85832999999998</westBoundLongitude>
<eastBoundLongitude>-60.04002830191127</eastBoundLongitude>
<southBoundLatitude>7.909833714326176</southBoundLatitude>
<northBoundLatitude>45.836119999999994</northBoundLatitude>
</EX_GeographicBoundingBox>
<BoundingBox CRS="CRS:84" minx="-97.85832999999998" miny="7.909833714326176"     maxx="-60.04002830191127" maxy="45.836119999999994"/>
<BoundingBox CRS="EPSG:3857" minx="-1.0893539465480125E7" miny="883328.9605809754" maxx="-6683625.377782496" maxy="5754126.115239219"/>
<Style>
  <Name>my-raster</Name>
  <Title>A raster style</Title>
  <LegendURL width="800" height="400">
    <Format>image/png</Format>
    <OnlineResource xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="https://geoserver.example.org/geoserver/Workspace1/ows?service=WMS&request=GetLegendGraphic&format=image%2Fpng&width=20&height=20&layer=layer_name"/>
  </LegendURL>
</Style>
```

Can some setting in GeoServer make the correct legend size appear in the OnlineResource href?

I am trying to use GeoServer with https://github.com/TerriaJS/terriajs and that appears to use the OnlineResource href link to retrieve the legend graphic.